# SQL SUM multiple columns and match based on multiple values in one column

Tags: sql

I need help adding to my SQL statement.  All of the Data is located in the same table.  My current code is as follows,

```
SELECT Date,
       Val2,
       SNumber,
       SUM(isnull(L1,0) + isnull(L2,0) + isnull(L3,0)) As TotalR,
From Table1
Where Val2='Rep'
Group By
```

Value 2 has both "Store" and "Rep"

I have the total of L1,L2,and L3 coming in great (for Rep's). 
what i need help with is how to get the

total of "Store" L1,L2, and L3 where 
SNumber matches "Rep" and "Store"

Some of the "Reps" are in the same "store" and should have the same total.

```
Source Table                    
Date    Val2    Snumber L1  L2  L3
x   Store   1   11  5   4
x   Store   2   6   8   10
x   Rep1    1   5   2   1
x   Rep2    1   6   3   3
x   Rep3    2   2   1   5
x   Rep4    2   3   3   3
x   Rep5    2   1   4   2
```

Result

```
Date    Val2    Snumber TotalR  TotalS  
x   Rep1    1   8   20  
x   Rep2    1   12  20  
x   Rep3    2   8   24  
x   Rep4    2   9   24  
x   Rep5    2   7   24
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use inner join with the subquery of the same table Table1.

Here below I prepared scripts for creating and inserting sample data you specified:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Date DateTime,
    Val2 Varchar(5),
    SNumber Smallint,
    L1 Smallint,
    L2 Smallint,
    L3 Smallint
)
```

Run this insert script to create data on the table.

```
INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 'Store', 1, 11, 5, 4),
(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 'Store', 2, 6, 8, 10),
(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 'Rep1', 1, 5, 2, 1),
(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 'Rep2', 1, 6, 3, 3),
(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 'Rep3', 2, 2, 1, 5),
(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 'Rep4', 2, 3, 3, 3),
(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 'Rep5', 2, 1, 4, 2)
```

And on the created table if you run the below script you will get the expected result:

```
SELECT Date, Val2, Table1.SNumber, (L1 + L2 + L3) AS TotalR, S.TotalS
FROM Table1(NOLOCK)
  JOIN (
      SELECT SNumber, L1 + L2 + L3 AS TotalS
      FROM Table1(NOLOCK)
      WHERE Val2 = 'Store'
   ) S
   ON Table1.SNumber = S.SNumber
 WHERE Val2 <> 'Store'
```

Try on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c203/1)

**ADDITION:**
The below script lists repos for the store with the maximum TotalS:

```
SELECT Date, Val2, Table1.SNumber, (L1 + L2 + L3) AS TotalR, S.TotalS
FROM Table1(NOLOCK)
  JOIN (
      SELECT TOP 1 SNumber, L1 + L2 + L3 AS TotalS
      FROM Table1(NOLOCK)
      WHERE Val2 = 'Store'
      ORDER BY TotalS DESC
   ) S
   ON Table1.SNumber = S.SNumber
 WHERE Val2 <> 'Store'
```

Comment: Awesome! Defiantly a step in the right direction. any recommendation on removing duplicate entries?

Comment: I am getting two entries for TotalS.  The higher value of the two is the correct amount.  I need to remove the row with the lower amount.

Comment: Edited my answer with ADDITION, check the above solution. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: The code looks like it will give me the result! Ill have to try it tomorrow! Maybe this is for a seperate question but the end result is to devide TotalR by TotalS to get a contribution %. I cant thabk you enough for the support!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  b.Date,
        b.Val2,
        b.Snumber,
        L1+L2+L3 AS TotalR,
        SUM(L1+L2+L3) OVER (PARTITION BY Snumber)
FROM    (
            SELECT  Val2
            FROM    Table1
            WHERE   Val2 LIKE 'Rep%'
        ) a
        JOIN Table1 b
            ON a.Val2 = b.Val2
```